# Stream Audio with Socket.io using Golang

Tags: go, socket.io

I have developed a golang application (multiplayer game backend) using socket.io.
I am using socket.io plugin made in golang.
Now i want to stream audio between peers.
So do you know any approach for achieving this?
I know socket.io stream library, but how can i use that in/with golang???
kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Socket.io](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) is useful because it is flexible and higher level, but since you want to stream audio data, you might be interested in [WebSockets](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket). Socket.io is capable of using the WebSocket transport, but in your case pure WebSockets might be a better solution.

This [Medium Post](https://codeburst.io/why-you-don-t-need-socket-io-6848f1c871cd) talks about why you might not need Socket.io.

This [other Medium Post](https://medium.com/@adriendesbiaux/streaming-pcm-data-websocket-web-audio-api-part-1-2-5465e84c36ea) talks about how to implement audio streaming using WebSockets.

This [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/12/create-real-time-chat-app-golang-angular-2-websockets/) and this [other tutorial](https://www.meetspaceapp.com/2016/03/29/tutorial-getting-started-websockets-go.html) might help you getting started in WebSockets in go.